# Does Gradle flatDir enable jar builds?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Gradle flatDir local repository and I wonder if I would be able to use a compiled jar of my program, without needing to manually generate POM. Will Gradle still build and use the dependencies in this situation?

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gradle can find jars in the local directory

if you have D:/path/to/local/directory/myjar-1.0.jar, you could use it like this...

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       name 'localrepo'
       dirs 'D:/path/to/local/directory'
   }
}

...
implementation name:'myjar', version: '1.0'
```

I'd recommend using a local path to the project, like $rootDir/libs.  Note, for a multi-module gradle project don't use

```
    dirs "libs"
```

because it will look for libs in each module, not in the parent directory.
Instead it's probably better to put all the jars in $rootDir/libs and use this:

```
    dirs new java.io.File(rootDir, "libs")
```